# Loading Electron Modules in Angular 2 TypeScript Application

Tags: angular, typescript, electron, systemjs

My goal is to take [Angular 2's 5 Minute Quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) and turn it into an Electron app. Which I can do by adding "electron-prebuilt".

[image: angular running]

What I *can't do* is utilize any of Electron's extended captabilites - for example writing to the file system.

I can build and run ["Electrogram"](https://github.com/onehungrymind/electrogram), but when I try to utilize some of the basic functionality contained within it I get an error in the console of my Electron application:

### Altered app.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { remote, ipcRenderer } from 'electron';
import { writeFile } from 'fs';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1><button (click)="doSomething()">Do Something</button>'
})
export class AppComponent {

  doSomething() {
    writeFile("c:\temp\doSomething.txt", "some data");
  }
}
```

### Error in DevTools Console

[image: App not working]

How can I configure the app to look for the Electron modules in their correct locations?

Comment: I just installed Electrogram and added the following line to the constructor of class App in app.ts: "writeFile('./aaa.txt', 'bbb');" (without quotes...) and the file is written in the root of the project... What did you change to Electrogram?

Comment: It's not that I can't get Electrogram to work, it's that I can't get electron to import into the 5 minute quickstart app and have it find the FS module.

Comment: I just started playing around with ts/js and stumbled over incompatible module loaders, client vs server, import vs require, etc. Too confusing for a simple C#, Python, Php, Android developer like me...
Instead of trying to add electron to Quickstart, I added the Quickstart app folder into a working electron application (Electrogram). That worked for me...

Comment: any solution found by now?

Answer (score 2):

Due to differences between module loaders I've run into the same issue. I use different solutions based on how the app is being build.

**Webpack:**

[Webpack](https://webpack.github.io) bundles all modules and dependencies into a single resulting app.js (depending on config). In this case `import { readFile } from 'fs'`, works fine. The demo app [Electrogram](https://github.com/onehungrymind/electrogram) is using webpack.

To me this is the most convenient and fastest way of building the app and the most performant at runtime.

**SystemJs**

In case SystemJS is used as module loader I have to use the following to load the FS module:

```
let remote = require('electron').remote;
let fs = remote.require('fs');
...
let data = fs.readFileSync(this.dbFilename);
```

Hope this helps.

(PS. Do I understand all of this? No, I don't...)

Comment: Interestingly, this only happens for 'fs' module but there is no problem for 'path' - although both are require'd() in the same module file...

Comment: @JindrichVavruska As I said... I have no clue what is happening under the covers...